# SwiftUI - drawingGroup() deletes part of image outside of screen width

Tags: swiftui

I have an image, most of which will be out of sight unless the user scrolls. To its right I will have quite a few views, so I'm forced to call `.drawingGroup()` for performance. However, everything that is outside the screen's bounds when the app loads disappears when calling the modifier, so the part of the image that was supposed to show when scrolling is not there.

This seems to be the modifier's expected behavior. Is there a way to get around it?

Example code:

```
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    Image("ExampleImage")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                }
                .drawingGroup()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling `.drawingGroup()` exclusively on the non-image part of the view. Initially, the `Image` and `Rectangle` were part of a view but I had to separate them like in the example code. It's a really complex view so I wish there was another way, but thankfully the image is only on the left side of the HStack and there is no overlapping.

Example:

```
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    Image("ExampleImage")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    MyView()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .drawingGroup()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```